# Como obtener la fecha de ayer en PHP

Tags: php, html

Buenos días estoy realizando un proyecto en el cual debo sacar unos informen de una intranet y almacenarlos en una base de datos y la fecha la almaceno con el siguiente formato. (y-d-m).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego para ver los informes utilizo el siguiente código:

```
$hoy = date("Y-d-m");
      echo date("Y-d-m");
      include("conexion.php");//conexion a BD
      $result ="";  
      ini_Set("default_charset", "utf-8");
      mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
      $sqlsala = 'SELECT * from informe where fecha_termino ="'.$hoy.'"AND tipo_termino ="Sentencia"';  
      $stmtsala = mysql_query($sqlsala)or die("Error en: $sqlsala: " . mysql_error());
      $i=1;
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($stmtsala)){

      ?>
        <tr > 
        <td style='font-size:15px;width: 40px;'><strong><?php echo $row['id']?></strong></td>
            <td style='font-size:15px;width: 40px;'><strong><?php echo $row['rit']?></strong></td> 
            <td style='font-size:13px;width:40px;'><?php echo $row['fecha_termino']?></td>  
            <td style='font-size:13px;width: 40px;'><?php echo $row['tipo_termino']?></td>            
            <td style='font-size:14px;width: 40px;'><?php echo $row['fecha_certificado']?></td>
            <td style='width: 40px'>
            <select>
                <option value="opcion1">+ 5 Días</option>
                <option value="opcion2">+ 10 Días</option>
                <option value="opcion3">Mercedes</option>
                <option value="opcion4">Audi</option>
            </select> 
            <td><center><input function=modificar() type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-2" value="Modificar"/></center></td>
        </td>
<?php
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo cual se termina viendo como la imagen anterior. lo que necesito hacer es hacer la misma consulta pero por el día lo cual seria algo como (d)-1 pero no e podido pasarlo a una variable para poder comprarlo con el valor almacenado en la base de dato y así mostrar todos los resultados correspondientes.

Comment: Si $fecha_actual = date("d-m-Y"); entonces echo date("y-d-m",strtotime($fecha_actual."- 1 days")); En resumen, strtotime permite todo sumar y restar fechas: http://php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php

Comment: O directamente date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day'));